# How to change colours in the PDF Viewer from TeXmaker

Tags: pdftex, viewers

I'm already using a dark theme in TEXmaker. However, whenever I compile and preview the pdf in texmaker, it shows the document in white background and black letters.

Is there any way to make it more like this?

[image]

This is a picture from a pdf I have, with Adobe's view options changed so that the text shows in green, and the background in black.

I was wondering if I could do something similar for the pdf previewer in texmaker. I do not want to change the colours of the final pdf document, just the colours of the preview in texmaker.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thru xm1math.net, select Texmaker, then send your question (eventuakky in french) to Contact. The author normally answers questions and gives explanations to work easily with Texmaker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the output pdf, then change it back when you want to print. Figures may not be well shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}
\color[rgb]{0,0.7,0}
\begin{document}

Hello \clearpage World

\end{document}
```

Comment: To add to Vitor's answer, the following settings produce a nice dark theme. ```
\pagecolor[rgb]{0.15,.15,.15}
\color[rgb]{1,1,1}
```